# Where in the linux kernel sources can I find a list of the different keyboard scancodes?

Tags: linux, kernel, usb, keyboard, source

I was looking for a list of keyboard scancodes in the linux kernel sources, but I did not find anything. Does someone know where to find these? Especially the USB scancodes would be interesting.

Comment: I might have found a list in `/include/uapi/linux/input.h` but it does not contain the actual keycodes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *keycodes* are in `[src]/drivers/tty/vt/defkeymap.map`:

```
# Default kernel keymap. This uses 7 modifier combinations.
[...]
```

See also [my answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63688/what-happens-when-ctrl-alt-fnum-is-pressed/63700#63700) for ways to view (`dumpkeys`) and modify (`loadkeys`) the current keymap as it exists in the running kernel.

However, those are a bit higher level than the *scancodes* sent by the device.  Those *might* be what's in the table at the top of `[src]/drivers/hid/hid-input.c`, however, since they come from *the device*, you don't need the linux kernel source to find out [what they are](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scancode#PC_compatibles); they are the same regardless of OS.

"HID" == *human interface device*.  The `usbhid` subdirectory of `drivers/hid` doesn't appear to contain any special codes, since USB keyboards are really regular keyboards.

One difference between keycodes and scancodes is that scancodes are more granular -- notice there's a different signal for the press and release.  A keycode corresponds to a key that's down, I believe; so the kernel maps scancode events to a keycode status.

Comment: Okay, that seems to be what I was looking for, thanks. But I still miss the actual scancode, probably I just mix up things. I learned [here](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-1.html) that when I press ENTER on my USB keyboard, the scancode `1C` is sent to the kernel. But I don't seem to find `1C` in `/drivers/tty/vt/defkeymap.map`. Is there another layer between them?

Comment: Whoops, I confused keycodes and scancodes -- have edited that in.  Decimal `28` is hexadecimal `1C`.

Comment: ...notice `1C` is the IBM PC XT "Return pressed" from that wikipedia link.