# Linux kernel dropping custom keyboard scan codes

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

I have a vintage IBM 122 key model M keyboard that I am adapting for use on a modern computer.  I am using a Teensy 2.0 to do the encoding and to handle the USB side of things. I borrowed the firmware from the Humble Hacker keyboard project (https://github.com/humblehacker/keyboard) and I added the extra keys in the build config. So far, so good.

All of the "regular" keys work, but the kernel appears to be dropping the extra keys (<kbd>F13</kbd>-<kbd>F24</kbd>, etc.).

Running `/lib/udev/keymap -i input/event0` shows the scan codes of all the normal keys, but nothing for the extra keys.

Running `wireshark` to packet capture the USB port shows that the **keyboard IS sending** the scan codes, but it looks like the kernel is just dropping them on principle.

I feel like this is something in the kernel drivers that is simply not delivering scan codes that it does not expect.

I would think that there would be some sort of "master" key map in some `.h` file in the kernel source somewhere, but so far, I have not been successful in my efforts to find it.

It is worth stressing that I am not asking about mapping the extra keys in X, like so many others before me.  This is a low level, apparently kernel related, problem.  Assume for the moment that I will not be using X at all.  What I need is for the scan codes to show up when I run `/lib/udev/keymap -i`, I can do the rest from there.

Comment: I know this doesn't help but: Why are you using the Teensy?  That keyboard should work with a straight PS2/USB adapter.

Comment: The keyboard came from an old IBM terminal, it's doesn't use a PS/2 compatible protocol.

Comment: Wow. It could indeed be that the driver is not passing the event on (have a look at the last part [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63688/what-happens-when-ctrl-alt-fnum-is-pressed/63700#63700)).  You could try `evtest` instead of `/lib/udev/keymap -i`, dunno if that will come out any different.

Comment: evtest also shows nothing when the extra keys are used.

Comment: Looks like maybe if you want to use those keys your project just got a bit bigger, lol.  The hardest thing about writing a keyboard driver will be learning the API, otherwise they don't look so complicated.  I haven't done any kernel stuff in a while, but this: **[LDD3](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/)** is still valid for 3.x, I think.

Comment: @user2543941 It's hard for me to confirm anything without having your exact setup, but I suspect that you can piece together a solution from here:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Apple_Keyboard
and here:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Map_scancodes_to_keycodes

Answer (score 1):

The kernel sees the weird scan codes and drops them.
I would try to get those scan codes values and then update the hardware database index.
So in short the plan is this:

- get the codes from dmesg output - dmesg should output something like this when the unknown keycode is pressed:

  ```
  Unknown key pressed (translated set 2, code 0xa0 on isa0060/serio0)
  ```

`a0` being the code value.

- create custom keycode mapping file. The examples and help are in the default file
  (`/usr/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb` for Arch, it may be different in other distributions).
- update and trigger the hardware database by running the commands:

  ```
  > udevadm hwdb --update
  > udevadm trigger /dev/input/eventXX
  ```

where `eventXX` corresponds to your keyboard (you can get it by running `evtest`). You may also reboot instead of triggering.

Look in [Arch wiki](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Map_scancodes_to_keycodes) and the default keycode mapping file for the more detailed description (or in your distribution documentation if it's not Arch).

This is the reliable and simple method, makes mapping on the kernel level so works whatever display server, DE etc is.

Answer (score 1):

This website offers custom keyboard conversions
http://straypoetry.com/ibm-model-m-keyboard/

Based on information from this website:
http://deskthority.net/workshop-f7/xt-at-ps2-terminal-to-usb-converter-with-nkro-t2510.html